# Sorting selected features

Tags: arcmap

How can I sort table by clicking  one by one feature, now I am selecting the features but arc map sorting it automatically  according to OBJECTID.  I want, it should be sorted by clicking then I should give a sequence number to the features. [image]

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you exactly want, your actual wording is not clear to me

Comment: may be think the other way round: click (select) one feature, then assign the value, click next and so on.

Answer (score 2):

There is a GP tool called [Sort](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/how-sort-works.htm) that *may* do the sorting as you want. Be sure to test this one first. If the sort order is very specific, I'm afraid you would need to handle it manually.

For doing it manually, I'd suggest this workflow.

1. Create a new point feature class.
2. Start editing it and create point feature within each polygon following the order needed. That is, you would create the first point in a polygon you want to have the `Code` equal to `1`, the second point feature in a polygon you want to have the `Code` equal to `2` and so forth.
3. Now you have a point feature class where each point feature has an OID equal to the code number you would like to assign to each polygon each point is located within. You can create a new field to calculate custom code for each point as long as it is sequential and based on the OID field.
4. Run the [Spatial Join GP tool](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/analysis-toolbox/spatial-join.htm) to join the OID or custom sequence field from the point feature class into the polygon feature class.

If you think the order of polygons may change often, having a point feature class would be cumbersome as you would need to reorder points all the time should you need to insert a polygon somewhere in the middle. In this case:

1. Create a polyline feature class.
2. Start editing it and digitize a single polyline which would have each vertex within each polygon feature.
3. If a new polygon is added, edit the geometry of the polyline feature making sure it has one vertex within each polygon and its vertices follow the order of the polygons.
4. Use the [Feature Vertices To Points](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/feature-vertices-to-points.htm) GP tool to export the polyline vertices into features. Now you can just use the workflow above.

Comment: @MZia, how did you solve your task if you have? :)